# How can a display only the last 20 columns of a table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

So I know this may be a stupid question, but I lost a lot of time with it and I can't manage to do this.

I have this table (`class : responstable`), and in it's `<td>@c</td>`, I will display some values from my database. The thing is that I have a loooooot of values stored there and I am interested to display only the **LAST** 20 values -> so *only* the **LAST 20 COLUMNS**

-(under the value I want too see the date+time) ...

```
  <div class="tabel-val">
    <br><br>
    <table id= "myTable" style="width:100%" class="responstable">

    <tr  class="val">

        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;value</th>
        @for((c,w)<- map){
        <td>@c</td>

         }
    </tr>
    <tr class="time">
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;time</th>
        @for(k <- timeList){
            <td> @k</td> 
         }
    </tr>
    <tr class="date">
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;date</th> 
        @for(q <- dateList){ 
        <td>@q </td>
        }
     </tr>

    </table>
    </div>
```

I tried something with :

```
 $("table td:gt(5)").hide(); //displays only the 5 values (val class) , no time and date ...
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: you can check this one http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

Comment: Why are you looping over these values as columns? Shouldn't these be rows?

Comment: I have 3 rows and a lot of columns, but I am not interested to see all of those columns. I want to see only the last 20 (td's). I tried with 5 just to test it. ...

Comment: ... mmm ... ok, i know how to show all the columns, but I am getting the 5 first values, not the last ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this will CSS alone - with the `:nth-last-child` selector.

Just use the following:

```
.responstable td{
    display: none;
}
.responstable td:nth-last-child(-n + 20) {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

### Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/oqjLpntL/2/) (Where I display the last 3 columns of a row)

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  display: none;
}
td:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabel-val">
  <br>
  <br>
  <table id="myTable" style="width:100%" class="responstable">
    <tr class="val">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using the `:nth-last-child(n)` selector and a tilde (`~`) selector to select all objects after it.

```
td{
    border:1px solid black;
    display:none;
}

td:nth-last-child(4) ~ td{
    display: initial;
}
```

This example would only show cells after the cells a5 & b5 (since they where the 4th from the end).
In your case you would rather need to use `td:nth-last-child(21) ~ td` to only show the last 20 cells.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>a3</td>
        <td>a4</td>
        <td>a5</td>
        <td>a6</td>
        <td>a7</td>
        <td>a8</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>b1</td>
        <td>b2</td>
        <td>b3</td>
        <td>b4</td>
        <td>b5</td>
        <td>b6</td>
        <td>b7</td>
        <td>b8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a JSFiddle for demonstration http://jsfiddle.net/j2foq7hy/1/

Answer (score 0):

.First make a count of the available colmns. Then decide how many columns from last by the varaible 'iwish'.This is the code

```
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>13</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
```

The jquery

```
            var total = $('table tr td').length;
            var iwish = 1;
            $('table tr').find('td').hide().end().find('td:gt('+(total - iwish -1 )+')').show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
td:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
    display: table-cell;
}
```